# how to structure data type conversions for interfaces in go?

Tags: go, interface

I have a situation where I need to interact with a bunch of API's that all have similar purposes but different data structures returned. I need to operate the same way on data from all the API's but I then also need to maybe send that data back to the API at a later time so it can perform further operations on it.

```
type API1Response struct {
    Time time.Time
    Price int64
    Status int
    ID string
}

type API2Response struct {
    Price float64
    Status string
    ID int64
}
```

// and more API responsed that have irreconcilable differences in their structures

both APIs have similar methods, like `Buy` and `Sell` and `CancelOrder` so I thought I
could use interfaces to make my calls to the methods more usable but then I will have to 
make the methods return `interface{}` instead of returning their specific API response...

now imagine the situation where I want to `Buy` and I get `API1Response`. So I call the 
method defined in my interface but then I want to `CancelOrder` which needs me to send 
`API1Response` back to the API. How can I convert the interface back to API1Response properly?

the only way I could think to do it would be to make a long switch case that tries to convert to 
every possible data type but IDK if that is idiomatic or error prone in the long run...

```
if t, ok := emptyInterface.(API1Response); ok {
    //do stuff
} else if t, ok := emptyInterface.(API2Response); ok {
    // do stuff
}
```

How would you go about solving this problem idiomatically in go?

Comment: I don't think I understand the question, but I can say that a [type sitch](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_switches) is more idiomatic than the if/else statement shown in  the question.

Comment: thanks...the problem is basically that the reaponse from each buy/sell method will vary from api to api and i need to feed that data type to other methods of the api so i cannot just make a new datatype. so after calling the buy method i need a way to convert empty interfaces back to native types...I hope I cleared it up and didnt make it worse...

Comment: Perhaps you can implement the funtionality using [Active Record pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_record_pattern). Define an interface, e.g. `APIResponse` which has `Buy, Sell, CancelOrder` method, then define your API to return or take an `APIResponse` as argument instead of generic `interface{}`.

Comment: It sounds like perhaps you need a way to normalize the data... another than that is the data 1 dimensional??  A basic non nested map..if so you might be able to get away with using a map[string]interface{}

Comment: This seems like a design issue. If you can't use the generic form returned from you interface methods, then you may not have a valid interface; an interface is only of use if the implementing types can use the same method signatures, and in your case, they need to vary (specifically, they need different return types). You might be better off just wrapping them in a standard interface and exposing that instead.